# K-means clustering with z-order preservation for Canvas drawing optimisations

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry

I'm designing an HTML5 Canvas 'rendering pipeline' which would work this way(and in this order)

**1. The elements to draw exist in an array as vector data.**

**2. Data is assembled into Clusters (Groups of elements)**

**3. Each Cluster is rasterised(converted from vector to raster format).**

This rasterisation technique improves performance significantly as instead of having to redraw 1000's of vector points on each redraw cycle, we just redraw 5-6 images representing those vectors - kind of like a snapshot of the Group.

---

The problem is that grouping items together must satisfy certain criteria:

The Groups must contain items that:

- are *close together*, so as not to create huge Rasters where they are not needed
- are in the *correct z-order*, otherwise the elements will be drawn in the wrong order.

---

### Clustering Techniques tested:

#### Serially clustering as we loop through the items, without using a clustering algorithm

The naive solution is to split the items into groups(clusters) serially, in the order visited using a `for` loop, and just create a Raster for each group. This creates 5-6 images out of the dataset.

[image: Naive clustering showing large images being generated illustration]

*Note: `Raster` above is effectively the `Group`, since a Raster is created from that `Group`*

**Advantage:** This solution preserves the *z-order* of the items in the dataset, thus when the time comes to rasterize them they appear on-top of each other in the correct order. In simple words - they are drawn in the correct order.

**Disadvantage:** The problem is that naively creating groups can create large images which eat up performance.

Possible result of a "naively-sorted" `resultArr` below:

```
resultArr = [
[ // Group 1
 {"x": 20, "y": 500, "z-order": 1},
 {"x": 40, "y": 450, "z-order": 2},
 {"x": 60, "y": 510, "z-order": 3},
 {"x": 25, "y": 480, "z-order": 4},
 {"x": 55, "y": 460, "z-order": 5},
 {"x": 400, "y": 100, "z-order": 6},
 {"x": 420, "y": 120, "z-order": 7},
 {"x": 470, "y": 105, "z-order": 8},
 {"x": 520, "y": 40, "z-order": 9}
 ],
 [ // Group 2
  {"x": 470, "y": 500, "z-order": 10},
  {"x": 460, "y": 530, "z-order": 11},
  {"x": 470, "y": 510, "z-order": 12},
  {"x": 495, "y": 490, "z-order": 13},
  {"x": 500, "y": 100, "z-order": 14},
  {"x": 490, "y": 120, "z-order": 15}
  ],
  // .. and so on
]
```

---

#### Using K-means clustering to create more semantic Groups

A more sophisticated solution is to use [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to create Groups with items that are close-together, creating smart Groups thus creating smaller Rasters. This is what I use now.

[image: K-means clustering illustrating smaller result images for Groups]

**Advantage:** Far more semantic grouping. Items are grouped based on the distance between them, thus creating smaller Groups, thus creating smaller resultant Rasters.

**Disadvantage:** The problem here is that the `z-order` is of course not preserved. Therefore drawing this result array might, and it usually will, result in shapes being drawn OUT of the correct order

Possible result of a "k-means sorted" `resultArr` below:

```
resultArr = [
[ // Group 1
 {"x": 20, "y": 510, "z-order": 1},
 {"x": 40, "y": 450, "z-order": 3},
 {"x": 60, "y": 510, "z-order": 7},
 {"x": 25, "y": 460, "z-order": 4},
 {"x": 55, "y": 450, "z-order": 9},
 ],
 [ // Group 2
  {"x": 500, "y": 120, "z-order": 2},
  {"x": 495, "y": 100, "z-order": 5},
  {"x": 510, "y": 105, "z-order": 8},
 ],
 [ // Group 3
  {"x": 620, "y": 30, "z-order": 12},
  {"x": 600, "y": 20, "z-order": 10},
  {"x": 695, "y": 33, "z-order": 11},
 ],
  // and so on
]
```

---

#### Can we get an optimal solution?

Is there any solution of getting the optimal groups while *preserving* the z-order in the result clusters?

I understand that what I'm trying to achieve is impossible, at least getting a perfect solution.

Obviously I'm not expecting something that will be perfect but the optimal solution based on those criteria should fare better than the Naive Clustering.

I'm also guessing that K-means clustering, might not be the perfect clustering technique to use for this problem so I'd be happy to hear more ideas here.

Comment: Sort inside the group by Z?

Comment: Eh, no. Since a cluster might not contain a certain `z-order`, thus breaking the order of drawing. Actually what I am referring to in the question can't be solved correctly by K-means. I ended up rolling-my-own where I serially loop over the items and break-off and create a new Cluster if an Item is classified as too far away from current Cluster.